# ファイル名が 不明 で、ファイルサイズ 0 のファイルについて

Tags: centos

**環境**
CentOS7

**経緯**
FileZilla を見たら、ファイルサイズ0のファイル「Apr 29  2018」がありました。

**試したこと**

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hoge hoge     0  4月 29  2018 ?

$ lees ?
-bash: lees: コマンドが見つかりません

$ cat ?
```

---

**Q1.このファイル名は何ですか？**

- ファイル名はない
- 「？」
- 「Apr 29  2018」。これは、FileZilla が便宜上こう表示しているだけですか

---

**Q2.ファイルサイズ0の内容を確認することは出来ますか？**
内容が空なので確認することはできない？

---

**Q3.ファイルサイズ0のファイルはなぜできるのですか？**
・ファイルが壊れたら、ファイルサイズ0になる？
・ファイルサイズ0だとファイルは壊れているが、ファイルが壊れていてもファイルサイズ0とは限らない？

---

**Q4.ファイルサイズ0のファイルを削除しても良いですか？**
ファイルサイズ0のファイルが何かの役に立っていることはあり得ますか？

Comment: 確認ですが、`ls -lb` を実行(`b` オプションを追加)すると表示内容が変化しますか？

Comment: `lees` はコマンドのタイプミスですよね？

Comment: @metropolis。実行結果は「-rw-rw-r-- 1 hoge hoge     0  4月 29  2018 \r」でした。lsコマンドbオプションの意味は何ですか？「C形式のエスケープ文字を表示する」？　もしかしすると、「\r」は「C言語の復帰」ですか？　ということは、中味が改行コードだけのファイルサイズ0のファイルが存在している、ということですか？

Comment: @cubick。lessコマンド の誤りでした

Comment: @re9 ls の `b` オプションは "print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters" で、ファイル名にコントロール文字(キャリッジ・リターンやタブなど)が含まれている場合に、それらの文字をエスケープシーケンス形式(`\r` や`\t`, もしくは8進数表記 `\0xxx` など)に置き換えます。FileZilla で「Apr 29 2018」となっていたのはファイル名(`\r`)をそのまま「表示」してしまったためでしょう。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTPというプロトコルは元来、人の目で見て判断するものであり、GUIと親和性がありません。[FTPサーバーは思い思いの形式でファイル一覧](https://github.com/ffftp/ffftp/blob/ba3c51b2703af0d1380df1c823e67652cab998ec/filelist.cpp#L108-L504)を返します。FTPクライアントは返された文字列を解析しファイル名らしきものを探して表示しているに過ぎません。
FileZillaとしては`?`はファイル名でなく`Apr 29 2018`の方がファイル名であろうと判断したに過ぎません。

なお、ファイル名が不明なのではなく、純粋に `?` という名前のファイルが作られていて、`ls`は忠実に出力したに過ぎないと思われます。

2018/04/29にご自身がどのようなコマンドを実行したのかを思い出す必要があります。もしかしたらbashの履歴に残っているかもしれません。

> ```
> $ ls -lb
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 hoge hoge 0 4月 29 2018 \r
> ```

ということは**ファイル名**が`\r`（`\x0D`）１文字の空ファイルです。シェルスクリプトの改行コードが`\r\n`になっており、シェルは`\n`のみを改行コードと認識し何らかのコマンド引数に`\r`が渡された、そしてそのシェルスクリプトを実行したのは2018/04/29だということでしょう。

なお、FTPではプロトコル上、改行コードとして`\r\n`を使用することになっているためファイル名`\r`を認識できなかったのでしょう。

Comment: あと、「?」はGUI側のファイル名のエンコードから、サーバー側のファイル名へのデコードができなくて、代替文字として使われて、そのまま作成されたという可能性も考えられます。

Comment: @sanadan そこはmetropolisさんが確認されておられるように`ls -lb`の結果次第ですね。

Comment: ファイルサイズ0のファイルは、実際に中身のないファイルです。データの格納先として、予めファイル名を確保する目的で使われたりします。cuiで「touch test.txt」というコマンドで、ファイルサイズ0のtest.txtというファイルを作ることができます。中身がないのは「cat test.txt」やviなどのテキストエディタなどで確認できると思います。

Comment: 本当に不要であれば、ファイルを削除するのは問題ないと思います。しかし、作成された原因が特定できていないと、また同じファイルができてしまうことも考えられます。

Comment: ＠sayuri そうですね。まあ、回答ではなぜ「?」という文字なのかがわからないと思ったので、例えばこんなパターンが考えられますとコメントしたかっただけです。

Comment: 「FTPサーバーは思い思いの形式でファイル一覧を返します」初めて知りました。FTPはLinuxの一部かと思っていました。独立したプロトコルなのですね…

Answer (score 2):

コメント欄でも触れられていますが、サイズが `0` バイトのファイルは簡単に作成できます。
そして、サイズが 0 なら中身は何も無いと考えるのが自然でしょう。

削除しても問題ないかは、単一のファイルだけ見せられても第三者が正確に判断するのは難しいと思います。質問文では `hoge` で伏せられていますが、**ファイルのオーナーやファイルの保存場所なども加味して**判断する必要があるでしょう。

- 一般ユーザーのホームディレクトリ以下にあるファイルであるなら、なんらかのコマンド操作ミスで作成してしまった可能性があります。こちらであれば削除しても大抵は問題ないと考えれれます。
- 例えば `/etc/` 以下など管理者権限が必要なディレクトリ配下に作られたファイルであるなら、少し慎重に原因を追求する必要があります。(いきなり削除するのではなく、一時的にリネームなどしておき再度同じファイルが作成されるのか等)

Comment: 質問に記載していませんでしたが、システム系の ディレクトリ配下ではなく、cron 設定しているディレクトリ内だったので、多分何らかのミスで作成してしまったのだと思います。「サイズが 0 バイトのファイルは簡単に作成できます」なかなか理解し難いのですが、そういう仕様なのですね…

Comment: ファイルを書き込みモードでopenして、何も書かずにcloseすればそのファイルのサイズが0になります。openしたままプロセスがexitしても自動的にcloseされますので、同じくファイルのサイズが0になります。

Comment: 「何も書かずにcloseすればそのファイルのサイズが0になります」初めて知りました。とても驚きました。ファイルサイズ0は、物凄く特別な異常事態なのかと勘違いしていました…